# How can I prevent visual studio code from showing errors for embed typescript (<script lang="ts">")?

Tags: html, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using a preprocessor for my HTML files so that all Typescript code within script tags (like `<script lang="ts">...</script>`) get transpiled to JS code. This works great, but my editor (Visual Studio Code) gives a lot of warnings in the Typescript code, because it thinks that Typescript is not allowed within HTML files:

[image: VSCode warning]

I can't find any setting (or extension) which let me do this. The only setting I can use is `"html.validate.scripts": false`. That makes the warnings go away, but it also disables all syntax errors.

So how can I set up Visual Studio Code to allow Typescript within HTML files?

Comment: Just my opinion (and of course it doesn't answer your question), but scripts should not be inside html pages.

Comment: Nowadays everybody considers that wrapping `<script>` tags contents in HTML comments is bad practice (outdated and no longer necessary) but this is the exact kind of problems that it prevents. Just my two cents ;-)

Comment: You're both right I think, but that's what my preprocessor takes care of. It assembles components from the HTML and TS code, and outputs a TS file.

Comment: What preprocessor are you using? They might have a plugin that does that for you. This reminds me a lot of the single file Vue components, and installing Vetur plugin for VSCode will ensure that the files (templates + scripts + css in the same file) are parsed properly for syntax checking.

Comment: It is very similar to what Vue does with its single file components :) But I am writing the preprocessor myself (just as a hobby project to learn more about compilers and the inner workings of frontend frameworks). So I can't use plugins like Vetur unfortunately.

Comment: Well, there's a new hobby project coming your way then :)

Comment: I built a preprocessor too and was looking for a solution haha. Is there a solution to this?